# Adding large number of images in scrollView takes lot of time with stuck UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Hi i am making iOS application in which i want to show 1000 UImageview in scrollview. I have placed all images in project hirarichy having names

```
1_image.png
2_image.png
3_image.png
.
.
.
1000_image.png
```

Now what i do in my viewController's viewWillAppear is, I am loading all images in UIImageView in a loop and add it to ScrollView as subview after setting its frame.

It works fine but the problem is when i attempt to present this VC it takes lot of time with stuck UI since it is loading 1000 images.

I do all stuff in a single folder and here is the snippest

```
-(void)addImages
{
  for(i=0 to i<1000 i++)
  {
    get image
    set in imageVIew
    setframe of imageView
    add to scrollview as subview
  }
}
```

If a i attempt to perform this method in background i am not sure there could be problems since **UIKit elements are not thread safe** and can cause problem when manipulating them in background thread.

What is the best practice of doing it. Please advice

Comment: Why don't you use `UITableView`? It manages the performance itself.

Comment: Actually i have very complex view hierarchy that needs to be added on scrollview in grid view. That would be a great mess to handle using custom table cell.

Comment: needs to give iOS 5 support too

Comment: you can use the cell reuse concept of UITableView...I mean load only few images to the scrollView and then when user will scroll the scrollView go on adding the further images and remove old images from scrollView...

Comment: Give details of "very complex view hierarchy" because the table view approach should be a lot easier, safer and more effective than trying to load all images at start or doing the 'page' management yourself.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView.

Comment: even if you have to use UIScrollView you MUST page the images inside of it. If you can't rely on table or collection views you have to do the paging yourself. Have you looked at the memory footprint of your app? It probably uses a huge amount of memory. If you have only tested in the simulator or on a iPhone5 it might even crash on a device like the iPhone 3GS which has only 256 MB RAM. I would suggest to watch the WWDC videos about scroll views. They do this session every year, and it's always very helpful.

Comment: Take a look at this, http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content.  It is a tutorial about scrollviews.  The section about paging is great.  It loads only the images you are going to show.  I have used it when I have many images to show, and I do not notice any lag in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010891) or [UICollectionViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewController_clas/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012180)